Windows Failover Cluster - defining interface for Virtual IP
I have a 2 node cluster configured for SQL Availability Groups.  There is a virtual IP which is bound to whichever node is the primary in the cluster, and moves when there is a failover.  However, in my particular case, each node has 2 separate NICs, each with their own static IPs (one is a 1g and one is a 10g).  I want to ensure that during failover, the virtual IP is assigned to the 10g NIC - is there a way to do this?
